# Why does home_url() not work with filemtime() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, filemtime

I wanted to start automatically changing my enqueue version so I don't have to manually change it after a file edit so I thought about using `filemtime()` to pull the time but for some reason when I use it with `site_url()` or `home_url` it doesn't work:

```
function bootstrap_enqueue() {
    $bootstrap_file = home_url() . '/css/bootstrap.css';
    if (file_exists($bootstrap_file)) :
        $bootstrap_ver = date("y.m.d", filemtime($bootstrap_file));
    else :
        $bootstrap_ver = '1.0.0';
    endif;
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', $bootstrap_file, $bootstrap_ver);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_enqueue');
```

but when I pass:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style',  home_url() . '/css/bootstrap.css', '1.0' );
```

it works.  I've researched and read:

- [Alternative to WordPress's get_site_url()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580074/alternative-to-wordpresss-get-site-url)
- [Get the last modified date of a remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845220/get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-remote-file)
- [Get last modified file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448374/get-last-modified-file-in-a-directory)
- [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

but I haven't found an answer to why `filemtime()` it's work in WordPress with `home_url`?

### EDIT:

Further testing I've tried:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', $bootstrap_file, array(), $bootstrap_ver);
```

thinking it might be a sequencing issue but still doesn't work.  I've moved the CSS file into the theme's directory and tried:

```
$bootstrap_file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css';
if (file_exists($bootstrap_file)) :
    $bootstrap_ver = date("y.m.d", filemtime($bootstrap_file));
else :
    $bootstrap_ver = '1.0.0';
endif;
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', $bootstrap_file, array(), $bootstrap_ver);
```

all of them are still producing the same result and the version is being pushed to `1.0.0` so I think it has something to do with `$bootstrap_file = home_url() . '/css/boostrap.css';` just not sure what.

In the head I'm returned what appears to be correct:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-style-css'  href='http://path/to/server/css/bootstrap.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

but the Bootstrap file isn't rendering.

Comment: When you use `http://path/to/server/css/boostrap.css?ver=1.0.0` as a URL in your browser does it show the css file? Have you tried using only `'/css/boostrap.css'`, because `/` will take to the root of the website.

Comment: yes the file renders but for some reason it isn't pulling the version date.

Comment: Try this `bootstrap_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/css/boostrap.css';` (The CSS would need to go back in the root for this example) If that doesn't work try turning on PHP error reporting. It may show you some useful errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that PHP filesystem functions don't go off of URLs but absolute paths to files. So we need both the URL and the Absolute Path to the file so we can ensure it exists and get the file timestamp:

```
function bootstrap_enqueue() {

    // Roots
    // $bootstrap_abs   = ASBSPATH  . '/css/bootstrap.css';
    // $bootstrap_url   = home_url() . '/css/bootstrap.css';

    $bootstrap_abs  = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/bootstrap.css';
    $bootstrap_url  = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css';

    if( file_exists( $bootstrap_abs ) ) :
        $bootstrap_ver = date( "y.m.d", filemtime( $bootstrap_abs ) );
    else :
        $bootstrap_ver = '1.0.0';
    endif;

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', $bootstrap_url, array(), $bootstrap_ver);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'home_url' function echos out the home URL, which will break your code. Use `get_home_url()` instead, because that function returns the value, which means you can store it in a variable or echo it.

`wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style',  get_home_url() . '/css/bootstrap.css', '1.0' );`

**EDITED**

The PHP `filemtime()` function needs to get the files URL from the server root, but the wordpress  `wp_enqueue_style()` function needs the host root URL. The following changes to your code might work as long as if your CSS is still in your root directory. If it is is your theme directory just change `get_home_url()` to `get_template_directory_uri()`. If that doesn't work, then smoke me a kipper, I'll be back for breakfast.

```
function bootstrap_enqueue() {
    $bootstrap_file = get_home_url() . '/css/bootstrap.css';
    if (file_exists($bootstrap_file)) :
        $bootstrap_ver = date("y.m.d", filemtime($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/css/bootstrap.css'));
    else :
        $bootstrap_ver = '1.0.0';
    endif;
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', $bootstrap_file, $bootstrap_ver);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_enqueue');
```

Comment: no the CSS I'm calling is in `root/css/` and not in the theme.  I asked to know why `home_url()` or `site_url` didn't work.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Thats odd that your CSS it in your root directory, but each to their own I guess :P I have edited my answer.

Comment: `get_home_url()` is still passing the same issue

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Ok sorry. I am lost. I don't think I can be any help.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I have update my answer. Hopefully it will get you closer to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Close -- I believe the issue is that filemtime needs a file path asset, whereas you're trying to feed it a web URL.

I'd try something like using [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to point to the file instead.

Comment: didn't resolve the issue but shows the entire server path before the domain.